# How can I update the selection after edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a `TextEditorCommand` and need to update the selection after the edit:

```js
var sel = editor.selection;
let text = editor.document.getText(sel);
edit.insert(sel.active, text);
sel.anchor = sel.active;
```

writing to the `anchor` (or any other selection property) throws:

> TypeError: Cannot set property anchor of # which has only a getter

How can I update the editor's selection and where can I find documetation thereof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the selection can only be updated *after* the edit has actually completed, so this would be the correct approach:

```
editor.edit(edit => {
    edit.insert(sel.active, text);
}).then(() => {
    try {
        editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(sel.active, editor.selection.active);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```